# Alternative to $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, get

I've a gallery which should display different albums of pictures. 
When I open the gallery with the link, I add the album name with PHP: 
`<a href="gallery/index.php?album=nature` 
Then I get the album name with `$_GET['album']`. It works fine. 
But for Me is a clean URL important. And when I am finished with the site and upload it to a hoster, then I change the URL "layout" with the .htaccess file. 
So the URL `http://www.example.com/gallery/index.php?album=blacknwhite` change to `http://www.example.com/gallery/`. 
Now I think with the new URL, `$_GET` doesn't work anymore. Is there a alternative to $_GET to hand over the album name? 
Here's again the code sample: 

**Site with the link:**

```
<a href="gallery/index.php?album=nature">D</a>
```

**index.php the PHP part:**

```
<head>
<?PHP
   $album = $_GET['album'];
?>
</head>
```

Comment: Google for mod_rewrite. That will solve your question.

Comment: yes I will use the mod_rewrite. But $_GET still works?

Comment: Yes. Your rewrite rules take your "pretty" representation and map then to the "ugly" representation, so internally, the script is being called in the exact same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule should look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/?$ get_product_by_name.php?product_name=$1 [L]
```

It should not affect $_GET at all, so if it is not working it's because your rule is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to keep relevant information in your URL, and the album-title seems relevant in this case as I assume the page is centralized around it?

Make your URL work like this instead:

```
http://www.example.com/gallery/<album-title>/
```

Since you already seem to know how to use htaccess, rewrite the URL to your "ugly" one there if you get this type of format. Your URL will look way much better then.

```
http://www.example.com/gallery/blacknwhite/
```

Comment: +1: Great idea. :P I need the album name just for load the pictures. every album is a folder named like the album in the url. it have the picture in it.
so i can use mod_rewrite to get a url like that, right?
Other Question: can i simulate the htaccess with xampp to test it`?

Comment: "Since you already seem to know how to use htaccess"..
Now i start with the file. Nothing change.. I input some code, and nothing happend. i readed, mod_rewrite must be activated with 'RewriteEngine on'...? Is that right...?

Comment: That's correct, also make sure you configure the right folder with your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at something called [htaccess](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/), as you'll need to use `RewriteRule` which will make it pretty, but still keep `$_GET['album']` available in your PHP.

Comment: The URL rewrite is ok for me. But the $_GET still works with the shorter URL?
I can't test it, because i work on xampp, and not a real server with a .htaccess...

Comment: XAMPP works with `.htaccess`, just make sure that you have `mod_rewrite` enabled. And yes, it will work, so long as you have the `.htaccess` there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way but its not recommended. look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
you can use **$_SERVER**. but the correct way is using RewriteRule that well explained here: 
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?214564-RewriteRule-with-GET-data